# jquery after a form submit inputs are empty

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<div></div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="abc">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

$('form').on('submit', function(){
   $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $('div').html(data);
   });
   return false;
});
```

Everything works but after submit value that I filled into input is gone and it's empty..Where can be problem?

Comment: That is normal behavior. Form gets reset once the submit is successful.

Comment: And is it possible to set input values to stay there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, if it doesn't work for you tell me

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="abc">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<script>
$('form').submit(function(){
   $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $('div').html(data);
   });
   return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in process.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['abc'];
?>
```

Comment: yes, it works, but value that you fill into input doesn't stay there after submit

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say, this is what happens to me: [Photo](http://s2.postimg.org/54g4qcb3t/Captura.png)

Comment: Great! Do you know that you can view you javascript errors pressing F12 in chrome at the bottom-right part?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#submit').click(function(){ 
                $.post('process.php', $('#myform').serialize(), function(data) {
                 $('div').html(data);
                });
                return false;
           });
    });

</script>

<div></div>
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" name="abc">
<input type="button" value="send" id="submit"/>
</form>
```